# Wordpress: execute do_shortcode() inside ajax function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm implementing a wordpress frontend php page which holds a list of hyperlinks in the body and a wpdatatable in the footer.

I want to reload the data table each time the user selects a link and this needs to be done through ajax without reloading the whole page.

What i did so far:
I defined my action in *\wp-content\themes\Avada\functions.php* as the following:

```
function tenders_shortcode() {
    echo do_shortcode("[wpdatatable id=49 var1=".$_POST['id']." var2=".$GLOBALS['cgv']['archive']."]");
}

add_action('wp_ajax_tenders_shortcode', 'tenders_shortcode'); // add action for logged users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_tenders_shortcode', 'tenders_shortcode' ); // add action for unlogged users
```

And inside my home page i made the ajax call as the following:

```
function toggleTable(ministryId) {


    $.post( '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', {    
      action: "tenders_shortcode",
      id: ministryId
    }, function(datatable) {
      alert("success");
      jQuery("#tendersResult").html(datatable)
    });

}
```

where *"tendersResult"* is a div which should hold the datatable.

The problem is that the html of the returned data table holds css link tags and it always display "0".

Following is how it's displayed in the browser, see the 0 text:

[image]

And this is how it's displayed in the inspector:

[image]

Please note that i've done a lot of research before posting my question and nothing fixes my problem.
Any help is appreciated !!

Update: Okay, so i've added wp_die() as suggested by Fencer04, but my problem now is that do_shortcode() still returns "" css tags in the header and the datatable is returned as "display:none"

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your function to:

```
function tenders_shortcode() {
    echo do_shortcode("[wpdatatable id=49 var1=".$_POST['id']." var2=".$GLOBALS['cgv']['archive']."]");
    wp_die(); //Added
}

add_action('wp_ajax_tenders_shortcode', 'tenders_shortcode'); // add action for logged users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_tenders_shortcode', 'tenders_shortcode' ); // add action for unlogged users
```

Without wp_die() at the end of the function it will never return anything other than zero.

Comment: Okay zero is not returned anymore, but my problem is that the result holds "<link>" css tags and the datatable is returned as "display:none". I want to use the result of do_shortcode() as is and append it under my div.

Comment: I'm going to bet that there is some interaction between the theme or another plugin. Have you tried turning off all the other plugins?

Comment: I'm still new to wordpress, which plugins should i turn off ? Btw can you validate that the path of functions.php is correct cz i found a lot of functions.php files in my application

Comment: That is correct but you should not be updating the files that are part of the main theme. You will lose those changes if you (and you should) update the theme from the author. You need to create a child theme. You can google that and find out how that works. Turn off all the plugins and see if it works. You may see other issues with the site but you just need to check on this functionality. If it works then turn on the plugins one by one till it stops working. You'll then know which one caused the problem. If it doesn't work with all of them turned off there is another problem.

Comment: When i use do_shortcode directly in the page it works fine,  the problem occurs when i return do_shortcode from ajax call and when i compared the generated html of datatable between both situations , i noticed the difference is that with ajax the link tags are returned and the datatable is generated without wrapper.

Comment: The datatables plugin probably could run some client side code on it after the shortcode is rendered. I would contact their support at this point and see what they say.

Comment: umm... do you have any alternative solution/suggestion on how i would make my data table dynamic and reload on user click without refreshing whole page?

Comment: I would just build what I needed myself  but that goes beyond the scope of this. Just so you know the people that answer here are coming on on doing this out of the goodness of our hearts. Starting your response with "umm..." came off as snarky. If it wasn't meant that way I apologize.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your reply ?